# How to use laravel inbuild auth module with email verification

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I created auth module by `php artisan make:auth`

I Tried to convert registration success after email verifaction, but found all auth code is inside vendor folder.

for below routes

```
 // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

It creates user and login directly. but I want to verify users email by sending email with a token.

I know updating in vendor is not a good idea, Please suggest me to handle this, Or I should create my own auth module ?

Thanks for your time, 
Cheers.

Comment: if its possible through extending it would be better, if not create your own.  :)

Comment: Which code you mean is inside the vendor folder? Creating new users is inside the AuthController.

Comment: @MinaAbadir I am saying about "register" method

Comment: Yes and I mean register method, it's in AuthController.

Comment: I am sorry there is only two method exists `create` and `validator`

Comment: actually it resides in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php`

Answer (score 0):

The registration process goes through the method `register` inside the trait:

```
 /**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Then this method is calling two functions in the AuthController in the app directory, this you can edit as you wish:

```
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            //'token' => str_random(10)
        ]);

        //Send email to $user here
        return $user

    }
}
```

In order to prevent users from logging in, change the Auth Middleware:

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        if (!Auth::user()->validated())
        {
            return redirect()->route('error.message.route');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find anything new.

Comment: The fields are validated through the validator method. Then in the create method you can whatever logic you want.

Comment: Added some comments to the create on how to send emails.

Comment: I will not run because of  `      Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
`

Comment: Getting error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\pathonnet.com\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 63 and defined`

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your comment, what's wrong with Auth::guard?

Comment: Did you return $user in the create method?

Comment: sorry I just removed that now added, but the above commented line is auto loging, but I dont want to it till email verification.

Comment: You need to add that functionality in the Auth Middleware.